# int main() issue with argv parameter

Tags: c++, boost, argv, argc

EDIT: The following code is run through Microsoft Visual Studio 2013

I have the following script:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

using namespace boost::filesystem;


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    if (argc < 2)
    {
        std::cout << "Usage: tut1 path\n";
        return 1;
    }
    std::cout << argv[1] << std::endl;
    std::cout << "File Size is: " << file_size(argv[1]) << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

But when I run it with `ctrl+f5`, I get this message (which is predicted by an if-condition in the code itself:

```
Usage: tut1 path
```

It seems the number of arguments is lower than 2.

Why this happens? How should I avoid this problem?

**EDIT**:

When I remove the following line:

```
std::cout << "File Size is: " << file_size(argv[1]) << std::endl;
```

I get the "Filing.cpp" printed on my console which means
`argv[0]` value is Filing.cpp that further shows `argv` is getting the commands from command arguments of Debuger of project correctly.

But when I add the line again, I see the message `"Filing.exe not found or not built by the last incremental link;"`

Comment: Presumably, you're running it from an IDE. Which IDE is that?

Comment: @MikeSeymour: `#include "stdafx.h"` is self explanatory :-)

Comment: Yes, microsoft visual studio 2013.

Comment: Have you set the command line in the debugger?

Comment: No I have not and I have no clue how to set it

Comment: You need to add the parameters to use in the debugging session (if there are), in `project properties`.

Comment: `Why this happens? How should I avoid this problem?` Its in properties for the project.

Comment: well, I should then search about it. Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298708/debugging-with-command-line-parameters-in-visual-studio

Comment: Open Project properties, look in Debugging -> Command Arguments. Add your arguments there.

Comment: @MostafaTalebi, Project > Configuration Properties > Debugging > Command Arguments.

Comment: Are you pointing to the correct directory and file name. E.g. C:/codes/abc/debug/file.exe text.txt?

Comment: yes. I have created test.txt next to the Filing.exe file.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest solution would be to open a prompt in the directory of your compiled output and call your program and pass in the string of the filename.

e.g. `FileSize.exe foo.jpg`

This saves messing about with project config options.

The `if` triggers because the application filename is considered the first argument, so `argc == 1` which is less than 2, triggering the instructions.

Comment: except that you cannot easily debug it then (though it's not really clear if the op wants that)

Comment: @stijn I agree, but given such a simple program... :)

Comment: well. I add the argument `filing.cpp` but it still shows the message that cannot find the file `rest_of_address/Filing.exe`, I even have change the `Filing.cpp` to `./Filing.cpp` but still not change.

Answer (score 4):

If you are running it like this the number of arguments is only one (the executables name). If you are using Visual Studio (which you propably are) and you want to add arguments, go to properties->Debugging and add the arguments you want on "Command Arguments"

Comment: well. I add the argument `filing.cpp` but it still shows the message that cannot find the file `rest_of_address/Filing.exe`, I even have change the `Filing.cpp` to `./Filing.cpp` but still not change.

Comment: Remember that the default folder in Visual Studio is not the one containing the executable. It is the folder containing the solution file. Is that where you have the file that you want to read?

Comment: If you added as argument filing.cpp why does it say it cannot find Filing.exe? It doesn't make sense. filling.cpp is on another directory

Comment: @Alex Patchanka And it is the reason behind my confusion. I'm doing something wrong which I'm not aware.

Comment: Do you know how to change directories in a cmd.exe window? Can you change directories to the folder containing your executable?

Comment: Well. Yes. I use cd (change-directory) for this, but I see not .exe file in my whole project and its subdirectories. Why? I don't know. You can see my updated question

Comment: Ok. Filing.exe is your executable, the programm that runs. filinh.cpp is your source code and it is on another directory. Just put any file (e.g. a text file) in the executable's directory and add it to the arguments and run it again. It should work

Comment: I have done this, exactly, but still to no avail

Comment: Probably this will help if you haven't seen it already http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554984/c-link-debug-xxxxx-exe-not-found-or-not-built-by-the-last-incremental-link

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run a program with arguments please run the exe file by cmd.
Exe file would be in debug directory.
In cmd go to path of exe file then run command like ABC.exe then arguments.

Comment: And how is this different to what I posted 10 mins ago? And it isn't necessarily in the "debug" directory.

Comment: Only wording is different. When i started writing answer there was not yours.